# Scrapy: CrawlSpider not executing callback for a specific domain while working for other

Tags: python, web, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to scrap historical NBA data from https://www.oddsportal.com/.

Using the code below, the callback does not execute. However when I change `oddsportal.com` to `nba.com` I have no problems.

I am not sure why this is. Advice?

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from nba_scrapper.items import NbaScrapperItem

import re

class GetGameSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'get_game_spider'
    allowed_domains = ['oddsportal.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.oddsportal.com']

    rules = (
        Rule(callback='parse_games',follow=True),
    )

    def parse_games(self, response):
        l = ItemLoader(item=NbaScrapperItem(), selector=response)
        
        this_item = l.load_item()
        yield this_item
```

Answer (score 0):

Scrapy starts out by looking for the `start_requests` method in your
spider, if no such method exists then it looks for the `start_requests`
and starts creating request objects for each url in the list, using it's
default parse method, which is `parse`.  Since your spider is using the
`start_urls` list scrapy automatically assumes that the first callback should
be the `parse` method.  So when it discovers there is none it gives up.

There are two easy remedies.

1. change the name of `parse_games` method to `parse`
2. implement the `start_requests` method and explicitly instruct each request
   to use the `parse_games` method as the callback.

For example:

```
class GetGameSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'get_game_spider'
    allowed_domains = ['oddsportal.com']

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = ['https://www.oddsportal.com']
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_games)

    def parse_games(self, response):
        l = ItemLoader(item=NbaScrapperItem(), selector=response)
        this_item = l.load_item()
        yield this_item
```